# HTML code to upload file to dropbox or google drive along with name and email?

Tags: video, file-upload, upload, blogger, image-upload

I am embedding this code in my blogger page to upload a video file along with the uploader's email and name to my dropbox or my google drive. I am using the following code, but I have no idea how to specify on whose google drive or dropbox account (and folder) the file should be uploaded to, if it is uploading at all, and how is the information of the uploader (name and email) being uploaded along with the video file. I can't afford to buy web hosting space, so for now I have to accomplish this using blogger, dropbox or my google drive (all free services). Thank you in advance. You guys rock!

```
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<!-- Paste this into forms.html -->

<!-- Text input fields -->
<input id="name" placeholder="Your Name" type="text" />
<input id="email" placeholder="Your Email" type="email" />
<!-- File upload button -->
<input id="file" type="file" />
<!-- Form submit button -->
<button onclick="submit(); return false;">Submit</button>
<!-- Show Progress -->
<br />
<div id="progress">
</div>
<!-- Add the jQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

  var file, 
  reader = new FileReader();

  // Upload the file to Google Drive
  reader.onloadend = function(e) {
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(showMessage)
  .uploadFileToGoogleDrive(
     e.target.result, file.name, 
     $('input#name').val(), 
     $('input#email').val()
  );
};

// Read the file on form submit
function submitForm() {
file = $('#file')[0].files[0];
showMessage("Uploading file..");
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function showMessage(e) {
$('#progress').html(e);}

</script></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use cognito forms. They provide 100MB for files free